# How to set collapsable submenu only on collapsed menu (aka on mobile devices)

Tags: css, navbar, submenu, collapsable

Hello everyone and thank you for reading this !

I am trying but failing to get what i want, i have this navbar:

```
code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x4mcq4h7/17/

and i am trying to figure out how can make the submenu "yogastyles" to be a collapsable menu when viewed on mobile devices ?

When viewed on a phone (collapsed navbar) you can't access the submenu "yogastyles" since the parent menu's click brings you to a page.

I know about media queries but i have no idea how to totally achieve this, i have a js script that adds & removes a class but i can't make it work together with the hoverable submenu i already have ...

I hope i made it cleat enough, ask away if not.

Kind regards !

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site. And don't add the word "code" formatted as code to get around the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't view yogastyles on desktop either

EDIT: I looked it over. .dropdown-content has a semi-transparent background which makes it hard to see. Try giving a media query like

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .dropdown-content {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: I editted the above (although it works fine for me) but i don't know what to say @Afrophysics, my issue is that when the menu gets collapsed (viewed on a phone for example) people can't access the submenu 'yogastyles' so i want it to be a collapsable submenu item so that when its viewed on mobile => you can click it 'yogaclasses' => it collapse and shows the submenu 'yogastyles'.  Kind regards

Comment: I think I understand the issue now. Right now yogastyles is a link inside of a list item with an href of "#" (which will essentially reload the current page when clicked). If you want it to be another menu, you'll need to make another dropdown with an un-ordered list and list items for each item in the sub menu

Comment: That makes sense, since it is redirecting to a location ('#' was for the fiddle) i should name it otherwise , 'yoga' for example. So when yoga is clicked it collapses with 2 subitems being 'yogaclasses' & 'yogastyles' both being a link. Basically what i want is that when its collapsed that it is something like this : http://www.gooteach.com/tutorials/5/create-a-collapsible-vertical-menu where 'Tables' menu would be my 'yoga' and 'Content' & 'Comments' subitems would be equal to my 2 subitems .  I will try this out and let you know ! If not tonight definetly tomorrow. Kind regards

Comment: Thank you Afrophysics i overlooked the fact that the menu was already a link so clicking it anyhow will resolve into going to the page. This fixed my issue ofcourse so thank you sir ! Kind regards

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)